# Is it possible to update the text of a keyword via the API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Is it possible to update the keyword text via the API? We are using the PHP examples and we have seen this

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/basic-operations#update-a-keyword

but this explains bids and uses the `AdGroupCriterionService`. If you try to `setText` in place of `setFinalUrls` there is an error as text is for the keyword and not the `AdGroupCriterionService`. The error is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\BiddableAdGroupCriterion::setText()
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, in AdWords [keyword text is immutable](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/PZg183h9mM0).
The solution for this is to just create a new keyword and delete the old one if the create was successful.